# Set field to calculate sell price in Commerce

Tags: commerce

I've got two prices on each of my Commerce products; the standard price field and a retailer price field.

In order to minimize both possible manual miscalculations and time spent on adding products I'd love if the standard price could be automatically calculated based on a formula I provide (Retailer price + Packaging + Copyright fee + Payment gateway fee + markup). I'd need to be able to change the values per Product Type via the UI at any time.

I've never done any math in drupal so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checkout the Drupal Commerce pricing rules. That's the calculation system that calculate sell price of products when your users adds a product to the cart. https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-pricing-rules-screencasts

Comment: hi @PontusNilsson, sorry about the wait. Does is only calculate when hitting add to cart? I'd need to display prices before that step...

Comment: No when the line item price is calculated